# custom setter/getter for @property objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Have a custom property:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) SIListVCDisplayType displayType;
```

When I refer to it, it must be via `displayType`, not `_displayType`. Why? I thought instance vars need to have `_` before their name ?

If I write for example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *test;
```

Then it works....

Comment: Can you show any `@synthesize` statements and your actual attempted usage, where it is not working

Comment: Just FYI - instance vars don't _need_ to have an underscore as the first character, it is just a useful convention for properties backed by an instance variable. Also notice that (although it is a somewhat rare case) a property does not necessarily _need_ to have an instance variable to back it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say in any case you should use self.displayType IF you use @synthesize. If not (as it would seem from the title) you should ALWAYS create your own SIListVCDisplayType in your class and name it as you please.

If you create a property called NAME, you will seem to get a _NAME parameter in class as well in most cases. This is because of how objective C works, not how you should use it. Create your own and bind it to. I see no reason at all that this type of naming and creating variables behind the scene will stay the same, so unless you find some documentation saying otherwise it might happen your code will not even compile after some update.

Comment: [Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW6) `Unless you specify otherwise, the synthesized instance variable has the same name as the property, but with an underscore prefix`

Comment: Same guide: "In general, you should use accessor methods or dot syntax for property access even if you’re accessing an object’s properties from within its own implementation, in which case you should use self." Also note that the name changes to god knows what is you manage to make another parameter in class with that exact underscored name. And again, if they feel to change that it will change and code will be broken.

Comment: I was not debating that using the accessors is almost always preferable. I was just showing documentation for the naming. As it's documented it makes it less likely to be changed without upsetting a lot of people. Name collisions are a different issue and the compiler should scream if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you can access **property ivar** it using `displayType`?
I've tried to reproduce your problem and I've used @property with enum type `UAProducStatus` and I can't access it using `displayType`, but I can using `_displayType`.

What I can guess is that you either have defined local variable or ivar with same name, or you have 
`@synthesize displayType = displayType;`